# How to run two methods in parallel ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, methods, parallel-processing

I have two methods. The first one remotely executes an executable and the second one stars talking with an executable. The executable is a web-service. The first step does not return the true (executed through shell) because it starts and waits for the second step. Is there a way to execute the first method and the second method in parallel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use thread.

```
t1 = Thread.new do
  first_method
end
second_method
t1.join
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i've tried it but it hangs in second process

Comment: @HuMan It **does** work with ```#join``` . Just read docs what this method does http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-join

Answer (score 6):

Besides the stock threads support I'd like to mention the great Ruby gem [Parallel](http://github.com/grosser/parallel)

It can spawn processes in parallel **and** utilize multiple CPUs/cores at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ruby's threads to do that. 
You can check out the links so you can have an ideia of what you can do with threads.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html

Answer (score 0):

Use fork to run things in parallel, threads are concurrent but not parallel in ruby due to the global interpreter lock which processes one thread at a time.

https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-concurrency-and-parallelism-a-practical-primer