# Is there a way to run three looping ruby methods at the same time (in parallel)?

Tags: ruby

So I am working on making a script that runs pings on network devices then alerts me by email if a device goes offline. And the script works perfectly!

But I want to be able to run multiple of these methods at the same time. Here are the three methods (they are calling other methods, so just ignore that).

But I want to be able to run these loop methods all at the same time.

```
def esxitest
    loop do
    test = system "ping -c 4 192.168.1.229"
    puts test
        if test == false 
            test2 = system "ping -c 4 192.168.1.229"
            puts test2
                if test2 == false
                    sendalert1
                    break
                else
                end
        end
    else test == true
    sleep(10) #300
    end
end

def proxytest
    loop do
    test = system "ping -c 4 192.168.1.226"
    puts test
        if test == false 
            test2 = system "ping -c 4 192.168.1.226"
            puts test2
                if test2 == false
                    sendalert2
                    break
                else
                end
        end
    else test == true
    sleep(20) #300
    end
end

def domaintest
    loop do
    test = system "ping -c 4 192.168.1.227"
    puts test
        if test == false 
            test2 = system "ping -c 4 192.168.1.227"
            puts test2
                if test2 == false
                    sendalert3
                    break
                else
                end
        end
    else test == true
    sleep(30) #300
    end
end
```

Comment: Please fix some (if then else) syntax to let user run your code. For process in parallel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782492/how-to-run-two-methods-in-parallel-ruby

Answer (score 1):

when I first look at your code I have 2 questions:

1) How are you staring this code, would it not be easier to start each monitoring as its own process?

2) I see 3 methods containing a loop, why not move the loop to a surrounding method?

```
def do_tests
  loop do
    esxitest
    proxytest
    domaintest
    sleep(10)
  end
end
```

Comment: I found found this method while searching:

t1 = Thread.new{esxitest()}
t2 = Thread.new{proxytest()}
t3 = Thread.new{domaintest()}
t1.join
t2.join
t3.join

And that starts them all together

Comment: @dennisvandehoef - Good point. I think OP wants them to execute them concurrently. Can you think of how that can be done via Threads? Probably also point out that OP should remove `loop` from other methods as well and all are moved under one method instead?

Comment: @dennisvandehoef - Also I would suggest avoid putting questions in your answer to OP. For any clarifications/questions write a comment in comments section below the question/post.

Comment: @EricChristensen neither that nor this answer will run "in parallel". This answer will run them in order and using threads will technically just use a scheduling algorithm to swap between threads but they will run concurrently which for this case seems more than sufficient

Comment: @enginnersmnky oh okay; thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I am very new to ruby and coding in general.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multi-threading for this purpose. Basically, Thread is used to achieve parallelism.

here, it's a good read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm